# What is the relationship between the ﬁrst experiment and the second experiment that is determined by this probability function?

Tags: probability

Can anyone explain this exercise to me?:

> **Quick exercise 2.5:** Consider the sample space $\{a_1 ,a_2 ,a_3 ,a_4 ,a_5 ,a_6 \}$ of
>   some experiment, where outcome $a_i$ has probability $p_i$ for $i =1,\dotsc,6$. We
>   perform this experiment twice in such a way that the associated probabilities are:
>
> $P((a_i, a_i)) = p_i$  and $P((a_i, a_j)) = 0$ if $i \neq j$, for $i, j = 1,\dotsc,6$.
>
> Check that $P$ is a probability function on the sample space $\Omega = \{a_1,...,a_6\} \times \{a_1,...,a_6\}$ of  the combined experiment. What is the relationship between the ﬁrst experiment and the 
>   second experiment that is determined by this probability function?

So the solution given is this:

> **2.5** Checking that $P$ is a probability function $\Omega$ amounts to verifying that $0 \leq P((a_i,a_j)) \leq 1$ for all $i$ and $j$ and noting
>   that:

[image]

> The two experiments are totally coupled: one has outcome a $i$ if and
>   only if the other has outcome a $i$.

Please can someone explain this to me? :(
What's happening here?

I know that all the probabilities in omega summed will equal to $1$.. it has to, at least that's what I know. Given the $P((a_i, a_j))$, $a_j$ will eventually be different than $a_i$ since we multiply the sample spaces and we will have $36$ permutations. So this makes the probability unequal, unfair... it's not like tossing a coin where you have $1/2$ probability of an outcome, you should have in our case $1/36$ to be equally likely, but given that if $a_j\ne a_i$ then the $P((a_i,a_j))=0$.So there will be for sure one $P$ that will be $0$, UNLESS you set all the $a$'s to be the same number.... so example would be $W=\{a_1 = 1, a_2 = 1, a_3 = 1, \cdots, a_6 = 1\}$

Comment: Please explain what you do not understand.

Comment: I kinda understand the answer to the problem, but I don't understand his question... I would never think about producing the result that was given in the answer... I would be stuck.. I cant understand what's being asked of me to do. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making the assumption that the two experiments are independent, which they are not.  Since the probability that the first experiment results in $a_1$ is $p_1$ and the chance that the two experiments both get $a_1$ is also $p_1$, the second experiment must result in $a_1$ every time the first one does.  The same reasoning shows that the second experiment must have the same result as the first, whatever the result of the first.

Comment: Still can't understand :(
I know that ai = pi which means that the probability of ai happenign is pi, but where does aj come in?

Comment: ai is an event, pi is a probability.  The point is that the chance of two ai's in succession is the same as the first ai.  When they say $P(a_i,a_j)=0$ for $i \neq j$, you never have two different events in succession